# Find closest number in integer array

Tags: c++, arrays, closest

Given an array of sorted integers, I want to find the closest value to a given number. Array may contain duplicate values and negative numbers.
An example :
Input :arr[] = {-5, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9}; 
       Target number = 4
Output : 5

Which is the fastest algorithm? binary search? STL find algortithms?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please read [ask] with a [mcve]

Comment: am gonna go with binary search x) i dont think there could be a faster way

Comment: Binary search - std::lower_bound, check the returned iterator if it is not an end iterator and iterator before if it exists.

Comment: binary search can work only when the array is sorted. Otherwise, there is no choice but exhaustive search.

Comment: it's mentioned that the array is sorted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an algorithm in the `std` library that does almost exactly what you are asking for: [`std::lower_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound)

> Returns an iterator pointing to the first element in the range [first,
>   last) that is not less than (i.e. greater or equal to) value, or last
>   if no such element is found.

You can use this to find the first element that is equal or higher than your target. The answer is either that number of the number that precedes it.

---

Check the following example:

```
int find_closest(const vector<int>& A, const int a)
{
    if(A.size() <=0)
        throw std::invalid_argument("empty array");

    const auto lb = std::lower_bound(A.begin(), A.end(), a);
    int ans = lb!= A.end() ? *lb : A.back();
    if (lb != A.begin()) {
        auto prec = lb - 1;
        if (abs(ans - a) > abs(*prec - a))
            ans = *prec;
    }

    return ans;
}
```

The complexity of this approach is logarithmic in the size of the input collection as `lower_bound` performs a binary search. 
This is much faster than a naive solution in which you would loop over the whole collection and check every element one by one.

Comment: `std::lower_bound` assumes that the array is sorted.

Comment: @ALX23z The array is sorted. Read the question again =)

Comment: Sry. MB. However, this algo doesn't find the closest value. You ought to adjust the iterator a bit.

Comment: No, it will return a value, that is _not less than_ the given value. Try and search for 3. It will return 5, but should be 2.

Comment: Final edge case would be, if you search for a element, that is larger that all values in the vector, it must return `A.back()` or throw if `A.empty()`.

Comment: Correct solution - however to be a true answer to the stated question you should explain that this is a binary search, and that this is better than `std::find` because it is logarithmic whereas find is not. (And that no faster algorithm exists)